# Adding two columns from two tables in sql

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have two tables called `owner` and `condo_unit` and I need to get selected information from both of the tables. These are my two tables below:

**Owner**

```
OwnerNum, LastName, FirstName, Adress
```

**Condo_Unit**

```
Condo_ID, LocationNum, OwnerNum
```

How do I get one of the `OwnerNum`, `LastName` and `LocationNum`? I'm struggling with this since there is an `OwnerNum` in each of the tables. Just started learning SQL so I'm a bit confused on how to do so. If anyone can help that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `Inner Join/Join`.

```
SELECT
        o.OwnerNum,
        o.LastName,
        cu.LocationNum
FROM
        owner o -- o and cu (below) are alias for owner and condo_unit table respectively, you can use owner.ownerNum too, but it becomes messy when used with lot of tables and tables with big names 
JOIN
        condo_unit cu
        ON cu.ownernum = o.ownernum -- this line joins two tables on a common column/id and retrieves common records for the selected columns
```

Joins help you to conditionally select common data from multiple tables. There are multiple joins like Left Join, Right join, Inner Join. It's good that you are learning them - they are very important for any kind of web-development and also for writing complex queries later on in the career.

For starters you can follow this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

Just `join`:

```
select o.ownernum, o.lastname, cu.locationnum
from owner o
inner join condo_unit cu on cu.ownernum = o.ownernum
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join query

```
  SELECT 
OW.OWNERNUM,
OW.LASTNAME,
CO.LOCATIONNUM
FROM OWNER OW INNER JOIN CONDO_UNIT CO 
ON OW.OWNERNUM=CO.OWNERNUM
```